# What is the best practice to store time series data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I want to store time series data (price changes over the datetime) in MongoDB. I want to know which of these two approaches is better?

**First**, store the price data of *each date* *separately* in a field. Like as following example, which for each date, I store an array of price and time:

```
{ 
  "item" : "I1",
  "Price" : 
     {
         "2020-07-01": [{"t":t1, "v":1000}, {"t":t2, "v":1500}, {"t":t3, "v":1350}, ..],
         "2020-07-02": [{"t":t1, "v":1200}, {"t":t2, "v":1250}, {"t":t3, "v":1050}, ..],
         "2020-07-04": [{"t":t1, "v":1050}, {"t":t2, "v":1400}, {"t":t3, "v":1300}, ..],
         ...
     } 
 },
 { 
   "item" : "I2",
   "Price" :
     {
         "2020-07-01": [{"t":t1, "v":1025}, {"t":t2, "v":1200}, {"t":t3, "v":1400}, ..],
         "2020-07-02": [{"t":t1, "v":1560}, {"t":t2, "v":1050}, {"t":t3, "v":1350}, ..],
         ...
     }
 }
```

**The second**, for each price change, store the date value, like as:

```
{ 
  "item" : "I1",
  "Price" : 
      [
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t1, "v":1000}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t2, "v":1500}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t3, "v":1350},
          ...
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t1, "v":1200},
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t2, "v":1250},
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t3, "v":1050},
          ...
          {"d": "2020-07-04", "t":t1, "v":1050}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-04", "t":t2, "v":1400}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-04", "t":t3, "v":1300}, 
          ...
      ] 
 },
 { 
   "item" : "I2",
   "Price" :
      [
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t1, "v":1025}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t2, "v":1200}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-01", "t":t3, "v":1400},
          ...
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t1, "v":1560}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t2, "v":1050}, 
          {"d": "2020-07-02", "t":t3, "v":1350}, 
          ...
      ]
 }
```

I have more than 100 millions of records and I need queries like as maximum/minimum/average (/trend of) price changes of items over time in a specific date or last week/month/year.
I wondering which of the following approaches is better and will have better performance for above queries?
Thanks

Comment: Do not complicate your collection. 
"Price" : 
     {
         "2020-07-01": {"P" : [{"t":t1, "v":1000}, {"t":t2, "v":1500}, {"t":t3, "v":1350}, ..]},
         "2020-07-02": {"P" : [{"t":t1, "v":1200}, {"t":t2, "v":1250}, {"t":t3, "v":1050}, ..]},
         ...
     }
 

this series is better(for you to pick mean of price b/w date range) but you might have different versions within the same date.So it is better to store date timestamp as long so that you can store different price within same date.

Comment: You could also remove "P" as it is redundant and store longtimestamp : priceobjectArray [{}{}{}...{}]

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I removed "P" in above example. I just wondering about the performance of queries such as "Maximum price in last months" in first approach! For this query, I had to use $objectToArray to first convert price to array. So, I wondering this conversion is not time consuming?

Comment: This would of course be time consuming but you could filter the mongo select query to filter the required dates and consolidate to arraylist - so the size would be lesser compared to the main collection. This would save time unless the whole collection is selected.

Comment: I think dynamic field names is not a smart design, you will have to covert them again and again.

Comment: Dates should be stored as `Date` objects, not as string.